# Cartesian product without commutative tuples

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics

N iterators are given. Task is to get the cartesian product of those iterators (in the form of a collection of tuples each N elements wide) while also discarding tuples that can be derived from other tuples by simply rearranging the elements in them.
For example if we have `(1, 2, 3)`, `(1, 2)` and `(7, 8, 9)`, we may get `(1, 2, 7)` and `(2, 1, 7)`. These tuples have the same elements in them, just in different order. Task is to only **retain one** of them and **discard all of the others**.

I am familiar with `itertools.product` as well as the other combinatorial functions, but after testing all of them they don't provide the result I want. I hope I can be forgiven for not attaching code examples of me trying those functions and observing the presence of commutative pairs in the results.

I also need to say all kinds of approaches that would involve me looking back into the collection and searching for commutative pairs are not viable. **All input sets are generators and the cartesian product must also be a generator**. I've dealt with huge cartesian products (with a list of 3 element tuples occupying 70+GB on disk) and needless to say that cannot be loaded into memory and searched.

So what I'm hoping for is some clever mathematical trick that I'm not aware of or perhaps `next()`-ing some of the input iterators

EDIT: Adding necessary code examples according to comments to question:

```py
from itertools import product as p
one, two, three = (1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (7, 8, 9)
output = list(p(one, two, three))
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 7)
[...]
(1, 2, 7)
[...]
(2, 1, 7)
[...]
```

As we can see we get at least 2 commutative pairs after instantiation

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please read the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  A question should include the code you have written so far attempting to solve the problem, an explanation of why it doesn't work or is not satisfactory, and the desired result.  Make sure the code is a reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: @Bill Do you really want documentation level code of me just using `itertools.product` and concluding "Yes, there are commutative pairs in the output". Would you perhaps like the MemoryError when I try to turn the cartesian product into a list and discard commutative tuples?

Comment: Yes please. Otherwise I have to think through what you have done in my mind and perhaps code it myself, which requires extra effort.

Comment: @FyodorRogov it would give us a better idea of where you've been. You don't need to post the memory error, but just saying "I've got arbitrary iterators" doesn't yield a solution. Are your iterators integer tuples? Or is that just a contrived example? We don't know, and the contents may influence the solution

Comment: Is `(1, 1, 9)` a valid combination?

Comment: @mozway Yes, `(1, 1, 9)` is valid.

Comment: All possible combinations of N items from N lists where ordering doesn't matter?

Comment: @C.Nivs It can be pretty much any primitive type. I just chose `int`s for the example.

Comment: @FyodorRogov then the answer changes depending on the type. Bool and int could be one solution, str is another. You need to be specific. Don't give contrived examples, give real ones

Comment: @JesseSealand Yes, but each combination has to be unique in such a way that no matter how you rearrange its elements, it will not be identical to any other tuple.

Comment: @C.Nivs It won't be strings. Just very basic primitive types. Let's do `int`s.

Comment: How big are the tuples in real life? How many of them? Which overlap of values?

Comment: @FyodorRogov again, how are they created. Is this an arbitrary homework problem? If these combinations are coming from somewhere, it would be useful to see the mechanism. What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: Subset overlap seems relevant, e.g. `(1, 2)` overlap in the first and second sets, and thus will be prone to repeating.

Comment: @mozway Consider this use case `product(range(501), range(-10, 11), (i / 100 for i in range(5000))`

Comment: @C.Nivs I wish it were homework. Excuse the duplication but I'll use what I typed in a different comment: `product(range(501), range(-10, 11), (i / 100 for i in range(5000))`
If it helps, imagine a unit test for a function that takes 3 arguments and I wanna test throughout the whole range of values that I know the arguments will be. Ideally I'd use Python to make this generator and I'll yield each tuple over a socket to another process that I will test. But that's beyond the scope of this problem.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yup. Vague ideas I had would be after you go through the first element of the first iterator `(1, ...)` as well as both `(1, 2)` of the second iterator you could perhaps `next()` the first iterator? So that you skip the `2` in the first iterator? But that's all very vague in my head.

Comment: The more overlap you have, the more expensive it will be to compute the potential duplicates. In the end your also have to keep track of these combinations.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit slow but just to confirm. Is the desired result given by `output = {tuple(sorted(comb)) for comb in p(one, two, three)}` (which in the example results in a set of 15 unique tuples)? So, the goal is to calculate this result but more efficiently, i.e. without storing a big set in memory or doing repeated checks of set membership during the calculation or by finding an analytic solution perhaps?

Comment: From what I can tell, it seems plausible to do it with very little memory usage. https://i.imgur.com/Ded3PjA.png Just precompute all pairwise subsets of length ≥ 2, order the sets into canonically ordered sequences, then temporarily ban duplicates that you've already gone through in corresponding pairwise subsets while iterating through them in canonical order. It has some space/time overhead that grows as you add more sequences, but I assume that's not your bottleneck anyways. Theoretically, a more space-time optimal solution could use a blend of this and the typical memory-using method...

Comment: @Bill Yes, that's exactly what I want. Ideally I was hoping for some mathematical set theory solution but there are no guarantees that implementing it would be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You say product, but order doesn't matter in the output. Limiting it to three iterables helps, and I'm assuming the huge size only comes from combining them.

Assuming each of the inputs fits easily in memory by itself, it's fair to make a set of each, and compute their intersections. We can check for duplicates on these intersections.

But we've also found that a cycle in the three values will cause a duplicate without triggering these intersection checks. I eliminate those by computing each expected cycle value and eliminating it, thus keeping only its duplicate.

Extending this to more iterables is ... not something I care to do at the moment.

```
from itertools import product

def unique_combinations(one, two, three):
    x_values = set(one)
    y_values = set(two)
    z_values = set(three)
    xy = x_values & y_values
    xz = x_values & z_values
    yz = y_values & z_values

    # possible memory concern here, need OP's input
    cycles = set(product(xy, yz, xz))

    for candidate in product(x_values, y_values, z_values):
        x, y, z = candidate
        # check for violation of intersection constraint
        if x in xy and y in xy and x > y:
            continue
        if x in xz and z in xz and x > z:
            continue
        if y in yz and z in yz and y > z:
            continue
        # check violation of cycle constraint
        if candidate in cycles:
            continue
        yield candidate

data = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    (1, 2),
    (7, 8, 9),
]

data_with_cycle = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    (1, 4),
    (1, 2, 4),
]

def test_case(data):
    results = list(unique_combinations(*data))
    check = set(tuple(sorted(result)) for result in results)
    assert len(results) == len(check)

test_case(data)
test_case(data_with_cycle)
print('pass')
```

Credit to Mateen Ulhaq (and probably Bill) who had the same idea for the intersection constraint, and Bill for finding a problem with that initial idea, so I had to add the cycle constraint.

Comment: I think Mateen Ulhaq is saying the same thing in comments.

Comment: What do you get when you run this with `x, y, z = {1, 2, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 2, 4}`.  When I tried it I got both `(1, 4, 2)` and `(2, 1, 4)` (duplicates?) in the results list.

Comment: (1, 2), (1,4) and (2, 4) breaks it as well. Still thinking, but leaving this up for the moment in case someone finds a better use of this approach. Maybe looking for cycles with graph theory to eliminate those dups?

Comment: passing test case with a cycle

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the usecase I had was this: `product(range(501), range(-10, 11), (i / 100 for i in range(5000))`

Comment: That ran to completion for me, so does it work for you? We good here?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but it might be going in the right direction.

I decided to think of a way to identify duplicates and select one uniquely without storing past combinations.  It finds values that appear in more than one of the iterables (but not 3!).

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def is_unique(comb, shared_values):
    for (a, b), values in shared_values.items():
        if comb[a] in values and comb[b] in values:
            if values.index(comb[a]) > values.index(comb[b]):
                return False
    return True

def non_comm_combs_generator(iterables):

    # Find the values that appear in two of the iterables
    shared_values = {
        (a, b): tuple(set(iterables[a]).intersection(iterables[b]))
        for a, b in combinations(range(len(iterables)), 2)
    }

    # Generate all cartesian products
    all_combs_generator = product(* iterables)

    # Iterate over all but only print the unique ones
    return (comb for comb in all_combs_generator 
            if is_unique(comb, shared_values))

# Example
iterables = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (7, 8, 9)]
output = list(non_comm_combs_generator(iterables))
[print(comb) for comb in output];

# This should be the right answer (see comment on the question)
desired_output = list(set(tuple(sorted(comb)) for comb in product(*iterables)))

# Check they are essentially the same
assert sorted(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in output) == sorted(desired_output)
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 7)
(1, 1, 8)
(1, 1, 9)
(1, 2, 7)
(1, 2, 8)
(1, 2, 9)
(2, 2, 7)
(2, 2, 8)
(2, 2, 9)
(3, 1, 7)
(3, 1, 8)
(3, 1, 9)
(3, 2, 7)
(3, 2, 8)
(3, 2, 9)
```

Although it works on the example and a few others I tried it doesn't work in all cases, for example:

```
iterables = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4)]
```

In this case it returns `[1, 2, 4]` twice.

Comment: I really like how you generalized shared_values for the intersection duplicates. I solved the cycles issue. Also, from OP's description, it is critical that non_comm_combs_generator be an iterator, but you can just move that list constructor outside the function for the small test case.